# Making sense of Book I, Proposition 7 of Euclid's Elements

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

One translation of Proposition 7 in Book 1 of Euclid's *Elements* is as follows:

> Given two straight lines constructed from the ends of a straight line and meeting in a point, there cannot be constructed from the ends of the same straight line, and on the same side of it, two other straight lines meeting in another point and equal to the former two respectively, namely each equal to that from the same end.

Consider the following diagram:

[image]

As far as I can tell, we have two pairs of straight lines ($AC$/$BC$ and $AD$/$BD$) which meet at two different points. However, we also have that

$$AC+BC=AD+BD$$

In other words, we have two different points and two different sets of lines which are equal to each other.

Does this not violate Euclid's proposition?

Comment: "*Each* equal to that from the same point". You would need AC to equal AD **and** BC to equal BD, not merely the sums of the two lengths being equal.

Comment: I think the part after "namely" is the part which is missing here, yes you can make it so that $DB = AC,$ but you can never make it so that $AD = AC$ while maintaining the other restraints.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Ah, thank you very much (as well as to bof and Stephen). I made the mistake of thinking that Euclid was describing the sums being equal. The confusion probably came from other parts of Book I where Euclid describes sums being equal (I recall seeing something along the lines of "We have $GH, HI$ equal to $JK, KL$"). Thanks again for the assistance.